# Space above and below inline content

Tags: html, css, xhtml-1.0-strict, xhtml-transitional

What is the space above and below inline content?

Visible Here:
  http://jsbin.com/vertical-spacing-weirdness/

you can see in white an area that is between the div/table and the span; yet the span has no padding or margin.

Interestingly, this space goes away when using a transitional doctype:
  http://jsbin.com/vertical-spacing-weirdness/2/

---

Something to note, in Firefox, the space appears in Transitional when you use a pixel font-size value that is divisible by 4 (4px,16px,20px, etc.).

### Edit- Solved / Why

Alright, so it turns out that the issue here is that the font-size is not the same between the parent (div or table) and child (span). The strict doctype styling makes more sense because the div height would need to change anyway to accommodate any text in the div but not in the span. So in both the following examples the div will be the same height:

`<div>text<span>...</span></div>`

`<div><span>...</span></div>`

With transitional styling, the div is only as large as it has to be and in the second example it will only be tall enough to match the font-size of the span since there are no characters the size of the divs font-size.

The Firefox glitch on font-sizes multiples of 4 is still weird though.

(Tested on `23.0.1` & nightly: `26.0a1 (2013-08-31)`)

---

I don't know if I explained clearly enough, please ask if you need clarification.

Comment: Setting line-height same as the font-size on parent div solves the problem, i think there must be something to do with how different doctypes calculate the line-height for inline content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply the font-size on parent instead of span it self, sample > div div {font-size:13px;}

Comment: The inline-block is actually unnecessary, but it is the mismatch between div `font-size` and span `font-size`; also ... (continued in question edit)

Comment: Yes thats a workaround, but the original question still unanswered, why different doctypes behave differently ?

Comment: browsers will behave differently based on doctype, you should take a look at the w3schools.com for more information

Answer (score 0):

Correct following css in your css file.

```
span {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #9999FF;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 13px;
}
```

For this url http://jsbin.com/vertical-spacing-weirdness change the following CSS

```
table {
    border-spacing: 0;
    display: block;
    font-size: 13px;
}
span {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #9999FF;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, it's the font-size alright, span doesn't need `inline-block` though